# Outlook Add In + Where to add the vsto, dll to install on a third party system

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I have a created Outlook Add-In with C# which on execution in Visual Studio 2017 adds the Add-In to Outlook.
I need to deploy it to other systems at work, I have the .dll, dll.manifest , the .vsto file but I can't figure out where in the users system do I have to store these files or WHERE in the registry to make changes to add the Add-In in Outlook.

I tried directly adding the files to the registry using `RegistryKey.SetValue()` but it did not show up in the Add-In of Outlook Application, although it created the necessary files in the Outlook Add-In folder in the registry.

We will create the MSI later after we know where we need to store the essentials on the users system.

The intended Outlook versions are Outlook 2013 and Outlook 2016.

Any help is appreciated.

P.S.- the application adds the Add-in when I run it on my system through Visual Studio, I need to install it on others system as well.

Comment: I'd use [ClickOnce deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/clickonce-security-and-deployment?view=vs-2017)

Comment: I tried doing it and was successful, but have also found a way of doing the same using WiX, will update the Question with that solution if it turns out to be successful.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys I found a way to do the same. Click one works too but I wanted some specific files to be copied to specific destinations. I used Wix for the same and used this asticle as a reference https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/11/13/wix-installation-vsto-office-addin/

Cheers.